# Rails 5 Return all records and include necessary association

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, rails-activerecord

So we have such case (many to many through):

```
  class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :contracts
    has_many :subscribers, through: :contracts
  end

  class Contract < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :company
    belongs_to :subscriber
  end

  class Subscriber < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :contracts
    has_many :companies, through: :contracts
  end
```

Please help us to return all companies and its contract by subscriber_id

More details for example =>

We have subscriber_id

So now we can get companies with needed association

```
Company.includes(:contracts).where(contracts: {subscriber_id: params[:id]})
```

But its return companies only with needed association but we need return all companies

Expected result

1) Return all companies

2) Each instance of companies companies[0].contracts should return only contract with association subscriber or return empty array

So we can build such json and exclude if condition in contracts block:

```
json.data do
  json.companies @companies do |company|
    json.id company.id
    json.name company.name
    json.full_name company.full_name
    json.owner company.owner, :name, :email, :phones
    json.contracts company.contracts do |contract| # => should return contract by subscriber_id or empty array
      json.id contract.id
      json.company_id, contract.company_id
      json.status contract.status
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try something like this

```
Company.joins('LEFT JOIN contracts ON companies.id = company_id').where(contracts: {subscriber_id: params[:id]})
```

Comment: We wanna exclude condition like this and just make one right request to database that includes right information. Іs this possible?

Comment: This request returns only companies that have contract with current subscriber. But we need return all companies.For more details:

1) If company has contract with current subscriber we return this company and company.contracts should return only contract with current subscriber

2) If company doesn't have contract with current subscriber we return this company too but  company.contracts should return empty string